Sveltekit: Cannot call `fetch` eagerly during server side rendering with relative URL
I am struggling with an error trying to put together an infinite scroll table.
It works fine until I refresh the page and then I get the error "Cannot call fetch eagerly during server side rendering with relative URL (/api/clients/getClients) — put your fetch calls inside onMount or a load function instead"
I can't seem to find any documentation that clarifies what it means in this context and what could make a difference with reloading the page?
<script lang="ts">
    import {onMount, onDestroy} from "svelte";  

    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    
    import Table from '$lib/component/table/Table.svelte';



    // Data
    $:client_type = $page.params.type;
    let limit:number = 30;
    let offset:number = 0;
    $:search = "";

    let headers: any = [];
    let data:any = [];

    let newBatch:any = [];
    let noMore:boolean = false;
    
    async function fetchData() {
        
        const response = await fetch('/api/clients/getClients', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
            body: JSON.stringify({ 'client_type': client_type, 'limit': limit, 'offset': offset, 'search': search })
        });
        let result = await response.json(); 
        headers = result.headers;
        newBatch = result.content;

        newBatch.length < limit ? noMore = true : noMore = false;
    };

    onMount(()=> {
        fetchData();
    })

    $: data = [
        ...data,
        ...newBatch
    ];    

    $: onChange(client_type, search);
    function onChange(client_type:string, search:string) {
        data = [];
        newBatch= [];
        offset = 0;
        noMore = false;
        fetchData();
    }


    // Infinite Scroll
    $:y = 0;
    $:h = 0;
    function handleScroll() {
        if(y > (h)) {
            h = h*2;
            offset = offset+limit;
            if(!noMore) {
                fetchData();
            }
        }
    }  


    // Click on Row
    function handleClick(event:CustomEvent) {
        goto('/client/'+event.detail.id.data);
    }
</script>



<svelte:window bind:scrollY={y} bind:innerHeight={h} on:scroll={handleScroll} />

<main>
{#key client_type || search}
    <Table headers={headers} content={data} on:clickRow={handleClick} />
{/key}
</main>


When the web browser fetches the first page from the SvelteKit server (as it does when you reload the page in the web browser), the server will run your SPA on the server, obtained the rendered HTML code, and send that to the web browser, so the web browser quickly can obtain and render the HTML code. The web browser will then start running the SPA itself, and from thereon it will continue to run as an SPA on the client.
In your case, your component immediately calls onChange(), which then in turn calls fetchData(), which then in turn calls fetch(). This is what the server complains about. You should instead use the  load() function.

Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have to use fetch() instead of load() as I want to be able to keep calling it when different variables change, for example if the user types in the search box. I thought a key block would work, but it literally does nothing, which I can't understand. Is there any way to only run onChange() after the page is loaded to prevent this error?

@MKC, in that case you should use load(). Wait for the user to submit the form for loading the new data, or listen to change in the input field, and trigger the submission yourself using client side js.
